# C language - Menu issue with multiple void statements and do-switch-case

Tags: c, menu, switch-statement, void

I am trying to make a menu with the options to compress a text inputted by the user and then store that value to be extracted in the extract menu option.

The issue lies in that it seems like the code isn't following the void statements, for example

```
case 1: compress();//compress statement
```

It seems to only get the printf statement in the void compress(void) and not the scanf, which it then follows with the loop of the menu.

Any solutions?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void menu(void);
void compress(void);
void extract(void);

int main(void)
{
    menu();
    return 0;
}

void menu(void)
{
    int choice;

    do
    {
        printf("Menu\n\n");
        printf("1. Compress Text\n");
        printf("2. Extract Text\n");
        printf("3. Exit\n");
        scanf_s("%d", &choice);

        switch (choice)
        {
            case 1: compress();//compress statement
                break;
            case 2: extract();//extract statement
                break;
            case 3: printf("Ciao\n");
                exit(0);
                break;
            default: printf("Invalid Entry. Try again\n");
                break;
        }

    } while (choice != 3);
}

void compress(void) {

    printf("\n-------------------------\n");
    printf("         COMPRESS            ");
    printf("\n-------------------------\n");

    printf("\nPlease enter a word/sentence to be compressed:\n");
    char txt[200];
    scanf_s("%c", &txt);
    printf("\nYour word/sentence is %c", txt, "\n");

 
    char comp = strlen(txt);
    int mask[200]{};
    for (int i = 0; i < comp; ++i) //loop until all leters are masked
    {
        mask[i] = i + 127;
        printf("\nYour compressed word/sentence is %c ", mask[i]);
    }
    return;
}

void extract(void) {

    printf("\n-------------------------\n");
    printf("          EXTRACT            ");
    printf("\n-------------------------\n");


    return;
}
```

Comment: Off-topic: `choice != 3` can't ever be false in your specific case as if it is, you exit already before. So you could convert your loop to a simpler `for(;;){ ... }` or alternatively drop the call to `exit`.

Comment: In `compress()`, you have `char txt[200]; scanf_s("%c", &txt);` — which is bogus in multiple ways.  First, `%c` reads a single character, and the character it reads will be the newline left behind by the input for the choice number.  Secondly, you should not be passing a `char (*)[200]` value (`&txt`) to `scanf()`.  Third, you likely want to read more than one word, so it isn't clear that `scanf()` is the best choice here.  You might be better off with line-based input via `fgets()` and then parsing the line with `sscanf_s()`.  Your printing also needs to use `%s`.

Comment: @Aconcagua I'll try changing it up to a for if statement and see if it changes anything.

Comment: @Ocelotter Won't change anything about the output (-> thus *'off-topic'*), you just remove a redundant check...

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I tried `fgets(txt);` but I get the error, `too few arguments`.

Comment: Apart from other problems, in the printing loop `mask[i] = i + 127;` is simply added 127 to the loop counter. `mask[ i ] = txt[ i ] + 127;` would be closer to what you seem to want.

Comment: `mask[ ]` is a `local` array variable that will go `out of scope` when `compress()` returns. `extract()` will have no idea what was in `mask[ ]` when it comes time to reverse the process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are scanning only one single character, and as `"%c"` doesn't skip white-space this is the newline character terminating the previous input.

You instead want to read in a string, and to be on the safe side you should add the maximum length to read to: `"%199s"` (note: one less than array size to leave space for the terminating null character):

```
scanf_s("%199s", txt);
```

Note, too, that as `txt` is an array it decays to a pointer automatically when being passed to a function (see above); taking the address of (`&txt`) produces a pointer with the same value, but of a different type: `char(*)[200]`. This pointer is not compatible to neither `%c` nor `%s` format specifier, thus you actually produce *undefined behaviour!

Note, too, that `scanf_s` (any function from `scanf` family) will stop reading at the first whitespace – a sentence might, though contain multiple words separated by whitespace. You'd just read the first one of them, though. So you might want to drop `scanf` for this input entirely in favour of e.g. `fgets`:

```
fgets(txt, sizeof(txt), stdin);
```

Note, here, too, that the previous `scanf("%d", ...)` did not consume the terminating newline, so you'll need to ignore that, e.g. by a preceding call to `getchar`.

<sub>Crediting this last point to [Jonathan Leffler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15168/jonathan-leffler) who hinted to in his comment to the question)</sub>

Comment: So basically, I need to remove all of my scanf statements into fgets or getchar?

Comment: @Ocelotter Well, using `fgets` *consistently* (i.e. everywhere where you now try with `scanf`) relieves you from having to deal with all those newlines, as it consumes them together with previous input and you can forget about the `getchar` (which you'd only need on *combining* `scanf` with `fgets`). Scanning then afterwards with `sscanf` would give you the `int` back. That's the recommended way, though not the the only one.